# Show a checkbox on all list elements when onItemLongClick

Tags: android, listview, android-checkbox

I have a sample listView appliaction. My row layout is like:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Row">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="4" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/check"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text=""
    android:visibility="invisible"/>
```

With checkbox default set to invisible on all list items, however i would like to show it (on all of them) when an onItemLongClick event occurs. I tried setting the checkbox to visible in onItemLongClick like:

```
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

But to no success, checkbox appears only on the first list item. 
Any suggestions appreciated

Update - this worked for me:

```
        list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            for(int index=0; index<parent.getChildCount(); ++index) {
                View nextChild = (parent.getChildAt(index));
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) nextChild.findViewById(R.id.check);
                checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            checkBox.setChecked(true);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have to change your checkbox status in your adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `view.findViewById(R.id.check)` instead of `findViewById(R.id.check)`.

**Try this:**

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        checkBox.setChecked(true);
        checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
});
```

**To show empty checkboxes on all other rows:**

**1.** Add an extra `boolean` variable `isLongPressed` to your adapter class and initialized with default `false` value from adapter `constructor`.

**2.** In your adapter `getView()`/ `onBindViewHolder()` method add an condition like this:

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
if(isLongPressed)
{
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

**3.** Add an method `showCheckbox()` to your `adapter` class to update `ListView` with `checkbox` visible state.

```
public void showCheckbox()
{
    isLongPressed = true;
    notifyDataSetChanged();  // Required for update
}
```

**4.** Call `showCheckbox()` from `onItemLongClick`:

```
list.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Long Click", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        your_adapter.showCheckbox();

        return true;
    }
});
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: This works great for selecting a single row and showing a single checkbox on it. Is it possible to show empty checkboxes on all other rows too as stated in question?

Comment: Thank you will try that when i have acces to my PC, meanwhile could you look at my update cause i managed to figure this out another way?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.check);
```

To this:

```
  CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
```

In this case, your are finding just a view without specify what the position in your `ListView` it is.

To show a empty `Checkbox` in each line, you have to modify the `visibility` and set the `check` attribute to false:

```
 <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:checked="false"/>
```

Comment: Same as in Ferdous Ahamed answer, is it possible to show an empty checkbox on the rest of list elements?

Comment: However that is not the behavior i am trying to achieve, id like to present the list with no checkboxes at all to begin with but only show them when onItemLongClick happens

Comment: I see, but this answer your comment above, it is possible to show and empty checkbox changing your layout to this. If you want to show them when onItemLongClick happens, just add the line that I add in my first Answer

Comment: Im affraid no, if i set the visibility to "visible" the checkboxes are gonna be there from the beggining. However in the question i stated that i want the checkboxes to be default invisible on all list elements and only appear when onItemLongClick happens. The line you suggested allows me to only show the invisible checkbox on the item thats currently clicked. I might have to try writing a custom adapter on this one.

Comment: you ask about " is it possible to show an empty checkbox on the rest of list elements?" to me an empty checkbox is a checkbox unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on the line in which you get the checkbok. Calling the findViewById is gonna search for the first item in the hierarchy with that id, which in this case is the first element of the ListView. In this case you should change it to view.findViewById, since that variable is the row that was clicked.

```
CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
```

Although that’s gonna work, it’s not completely right, especially if you have more elements in the ListView. If you are creating a new view every time you need to bind an item, then you are going to lose the visibility of the CheckBox. And if you are reusing views, then the CheckBox may be visible for other rows.
So, the best way to do so is doing this in the adapter. Just make a custom adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() whenever you want to change the view.

Comment: With this i should be able to show checkboex on all other list elements yes?